# Accessing request.GET or request.POST in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

In django view, we often call forms and initialize it with request.GET and/or request.POST values `MyForm(request.GET) or MyForm(request.POST)`. How can I access it in form class?

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
  #... more code

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #... how to access request.POST or request.GET here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>In your views.py:</s>

```
def your_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request)  # or MyForm(request, request.POST, request.FILES)
    # your view code
```

In your forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = request.POST
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

** Update **

Originally misunderstood the intent of the author. To access just the data given by the request.GET or request.POST arguments, you can access them via `self.data` after calling super on the `__init__` method.

Comment: This is a possible answer. But, do we need to add additional paramater? By its nature, django received request data even without adding extra paramter. I wonder where they keep the request value.

Comment: You can try `self.data`.